# Defining overflow direction of vertically aligned flexbox item

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with a single item. This item is horizontally and vertically centered. When the item grows taller than its container it overflows equally at the top and the bottom of the container. I would like it to only overflow at the bottom, and remain anchored at the top. Any ideas?

http://codepen.io/wilsonpage/pen/LzryK (view in Chrome Canary for latest Flexbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the standard Flexbox draft, a single flex item can be vertically and horizontally centered by using `margin: auto`.  You'll want to use this instead of the align-items property:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/EJdvn

```
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* you can remove this here, but its not hurting anything */
  /* remove align-items */

  height: 80%;
  margin: 5% 0;
  background: green;
}

div {
  margin: auto; /* add */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following on the flex item:

```
align-self: flex-start;
```

Comment: That would mean the item is *always* aligned to the top. I want the item to be aligned centrally, unless the item is taller than the parent container.